# How can I return a MySQL error properly to the calling function?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm pretty sure this is a simple mistake I'm making, but my lack of development experience is showing.

I'm calling a function to execute some SQL.
If the SQL processes, then nothing has to happen, but if it fails, I'm trying to return the error so I can handle it appropriately.

The calling function looks like this:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO ....."
                            
db.executeSql(sql, function (data, err){
if (err){
   console.log("ERROR: " + err)
} else {
   console.log("DATA: " + data)
}
```

The **db.executeSql** function looks like this:

```
var mysql = require("mysql");
var settings = require("../settings");

exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback){

  var con = mysql.createConnection(settings.dbConfig);

  con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          return err
        }
        con.end()
        callback(result)      
      });
    });
}
```

When I run this, I get the following for a successful insert (which I'm expecting):

```
ERROR: undefined
DATA: [object Object]
```

If I trigger an error (for example inserting an item with a missing field) I still get an *undefined* response for ERROR instead of the error object.

If I add a console log to the

```
   con.connect(function(err) {
      if (err) throw err;
      con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error:" + err.message)
          return err
        }
        con.end()
        callback(result)      
      });
    });
}
```

I can see I am getting an ERROR:

```
Error:ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR: Column 'appitemID' cannot be null
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning the `err` try

`if (err) throw err;`

This way the error will bubble up.  Here is a good read on error handling in Node.js:

https://stackify.com/node-js-error-handling/

Comment: Thanks Masoud,
If I throw the error it displays it in the console, but also kills the server process, so it won't handle it.

Answer (score 0):

I was right.. it was a simple mistake - I worked through it over and over again and finally realised what was wrong....

I needed to respond with both the result and the error in the callback.

```
 var con = mysql.createConnection(settings.dbConfig);
  con.connect(function(err) {
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      con.end()
      callback(result, err)      
    });
});
}
```